# wcf odata client - how to ignore null properties in request

Tags: c#, json, wcf, null, odata

I'm a freshman in this area and currently working with WCF/Odata client to test an odata service.

When trying to add some new entity via "DataServiceContext", all the properties with no values assigned will take null values as default, no problem. When the "add" action is performed by sending the request, the XML/JSON body will always contain the "null" properties, which will cause some issues there. We cannot make changes to our service for some historical reason.

Is there any way to configure behaviors of the "DataServiceContext" to ignore all those null properties when serializing the entity objects to be JSON/XML? Thanks a lot!

Regards,
Peter

Answer (score 4):

I am afraid there isn't such flag to let you ignore all those null properties.

But You could try RequestPipeline to work around.

```
dsc.Configurations.RequestPipeline.OnEntryStarting((arg) =>
{
    arg.Entry.Properties = arg.Entry.Properties.Where((prop) => prop.Value != null );
});
```